# Time Series Downsampling/Upsampling

Tags: sql, time-series, resampling, monetdb, downsampling

I am trying to downsample and upsample time series data on MonetDB.

Time series database systems (TSDS) usually have an option to make the downsampling and upsampling with an operator like SAMPLE BY (1h).

My time series data looks like the following:

```
sql>select * from datapoints limit 5; 
+----------------------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| time                       | id_station | temperature              | discharge                | ph                       | oxygen                   | oxygen_saturation        |
+============================+============+==========================+==========================+==========================+==========================+==========================+
| 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000000 |          0 |                  407.052 |                    0.954 |                     7.79 |                    12.14 |                    12.14 |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:10.000000 |          0 |                  407.052 |                    0.954 |                     7.79 |                    12.13 |                    12.13 |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:20.000000 |          0 |                  407.051 |                    0.954 |                     7.79 |                    12.13 |                    12.13 |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:30.000000 |          0 |                  407.051 |                    0.953 |                     7.79 |                    12.12 |                    12.12 |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:40.000000 |          0 |                  407.051 |                    0.952 |                     7.78 |                    12.12 |                    12.12 |
+----------------------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I tried the following query but the results are obtained by aggregating all the values from different days, which is not what I am looking for:

```
sql>SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time) AS "hour",
       AVG(pH) AS avg_ph
  FROM datapoints
  GROUP BY "hour";

| hour | avg_ph                   |
+======+==========================+
|    0 |        8.041121283524923 |
|    1 |        8.041086970785418 |
|    2 |        8.041152801724111 |
|    3 |         8.04107828783526 |
|    4 |        8.041060110153223 |
|    5 |        8.041167286877407 |
|  ... |                      ... |
|   23 |        8.041219444444451 |
```

I tried then to aggregate the time series data first based on the day then on the hour:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM time) AS "day", EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time) AS "hour",
       AVG(pH) AS avg_ph
  FROM datapoints
  GROUP BY "day", "hour";
```

But I am getting the following exception:

```
syntax error, unexpected sqlDATE in: "select extract(date"
```

**My question**: how could I aggregate/downsample the data to a specific period of time (e.g. obtain an aggregated value every 2 days or 12 hours)?